# Execute git describe in custom_target

Tags: cmake

I would like to write output of `git describe` as a string to a file, so I can embed the information in my binary (C++). This has to work across platforms.

The best I can yet come up with was:

```
add_custom_target( SubmarineGitVersion
    COMMAND cmd /c "${CMAKE_EXECUTABLE}" echo czstring GIT_VERSION = STRINGIFY\( > "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/GitVersion.hpp"
    COMMAND cmd /c "${GIT_EXECUTABLE}" describe --tags --always >> "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/GitVersion.hpp"
    COMMAND cmd /c "${CMAKE_EXECUTABLE}" echo \) >> "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/GitVersion.hpp"
)
```

This roughly works on Windows (is missing a `;` at the end):

```
czstring GIT_VERSION = STRINGIFY(
tag-343434
)
```

Is there any better/more cross-platform way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Common way for create "version" files is using `configure_file` command. Such way file will be created at *configure* stage:

**GitVersion.hpp.in**:

```
czstring GIT_VERSION = STRINGIFY(
${GIT_REPO_VERSION}
)
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
# Store version into variable
execute_process(COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} describe --tags --always
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_REPO_VERSION)
# The variable will be used when file is configured
configure_file("GitVersion.hpp.in" "GitVersion.hpp")
```

If you want to create version file on *build* stage, move above cmake commands into some file, and execute this file in *CMake script mode*:

**generate_version.cmake**:

```
# Git executable is extracted from parameters.
execute_process(COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} describe --tags --always
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_REPO_VERSION)
# Input and output files are extracted from parameters.
configure_file(${INPUT_FILE} ${OUTPUT_FILE})
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_custom_target( SubmarineGitVersion
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
        -D GIT_EXECUTABLE=${GIT_EXECUTABLE}
        -D INPUT_FILE=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/GitVersion.hpp.in
        -D OUTPUT_FILE=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/GitVersion.hpp
        -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/generate_version.cmake
)
```

Comment: I had to add 

add_dependencies(${EXE} SubmarineGitVersion)

in order to make my project automatically make GitVersion.hpp when building.  Even then, it only works on a force build because the project doesn't detect that any files are dirty.